# Python: What Programming paradigm does this follow if any?

Tags: python, paradigms

For the past two day's, I have been exploring decorators and how they can be used to create and modify classes without difficulty or effort. This exploration lead to this piece of code.

## Factory.py

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import functools


class Factory(object):


    def with_callback(self, func):
        postname = func.func_name
        def wraped(callback, *args, **kw):
            cbname = callback.func_name
            print 'Passing {post} to {cb}'.format(post=postname, cb=cbname)
            premute = func(*args, **kw)
            return callback(premute)
        return wraped


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict__)


    def register(self, name):
        def func_wrapper(func):
            self.__dict__[name] = func
            return func
        return func_wrapper


    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self.__dict__.get(name, None)


    def __setitem__(self, name):
        self.register(name)


    def __call__(self, name=None, *args, **kw):
        return self.__dict__.get(name, None)(*args, **kw)


    def copy(self, old):
        class DerivedFactory(self.__class__):
            def __init__(self):
                self.__dict__ = old.__dict__
                self.__class__ = old.__class__
        return DerivedFactory()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    import requests
    app = Factory()

    @app.register('process_response')
    def process_response(response):
        print response.content

    @app.register('get')
    @app.with_callback
    def get(url):
        return requests.get(url)

    x = app('get', app.process_response, 'http://www.google.com')
    print x
```

---

#### Here is a example use of Factory.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import Factory
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs    

class App(Factory.Factory):
    pass


Parser = App()

@Parser.register('get_soup')
@Parser.with_callback
def _get(url, *req_args, **req_kw):
    response = requests.get(url, *req_args, **req_kw)
    return bs(response.content)


@Parser.register('get_links')
def _getlinks(soup):
    return soup.find_all('', {'href':True})


print Parser('get_soup', Parser.get_links, 'http://www.google.com')
```

---

There are six main programming paradigms:

1. imperative
2. declarative
3. functional
4. object-oriented
5. logic
6. symbolic

Which of these paradigms best describe Factory.py ?

Comment: "There are six main programming paradigms" - really? Says who?

Comment: You are mixing up "programming paradigms" with "design patterns" I think... a Factory is a design pattern, but does not mean you cannot use OOP for example. None of these groups are necessarily mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Cyber: design patterns are indeed somehow orthogonal to paradigms. But patterns are developed as "good practices" to solve problems in a paradigm. Thus they "originate" from one or more paradigms.

Answer (score 2):

The design patterns (of the Gang of Four) are nearly all *Object-oriented*, on the other hand is a Factory some kind of function. There exist design patterns in functional and logic programming, but most of them are different.

Furthermore you cannot say that there are really six paradigms. Most of them somehow overlap as well (the object-oriented is nearly always connected with the imperative one).

Finally design patterns are not really bound to paradigms. Paradigms are *devices of thought* to channel *computational power* through. Design patterns are merely best practices developed for these paradigms. There is no real theoretical foundation why a *Chain of responsibility* would work better than some weird chaotic piece of code...